# problem on sending firebase push notification in app background in Android 12 and 13 only in ionic5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, cordova-plugin-fcm

We created project in Ionic 5, it's properly working on Android below 12 and 13 versions. But I got problem on sending firebase push notification in app background in Android 12 and 13 only. Is there is any solution for this? If you have any documentation please provide us.

Thank you.

provide the stepes to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you figure this out please let me know I'm trying to figure this out as well!